# Time Evolution of Position Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, time-evolution

I am trying to understand why 
$$e^{-it\triangle}xe^{it\triangle}=x-2it\nabla$$ where $x$ is just multiplication operator by $x$. In particular, the text says this can be seen by differentiating with respect to $t$.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which text?

Comment: If $\triangle$ is the $1D$ Laplacian $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ the formula must be wrong. $e^{-it\triangle}xe^{it\triangle}$ is nothing but the Heisenberg evolution of the position operator for a free particle with mass $m= 1/2$ (and supposing $\hbar=1$). The correct identity is $e^{-it\triangle}xe^{it\triangle}=x + 2tp$ where $p= -i\frac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I apologize for the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $\Delta$ is the Laplacian operator, i.e. $-\Delta=D_x^2$, where $D_x=-i\partial_x$, this goes as follows (but the result is different from the one you give).

Choose a suitable dense domain of $L^2$ where $x$ and $-\Delta$ are well defined, e.g. the functions that are $C_0^\infty$. Let $\psi\in C_0^\infty$, then
$$e^{itD_x^2}xe^{-itD_x^2}\psi=x\psi + \int_0^t \frac{d}{ds}(e^{isD_x^2}xe^{-isD_x^2}\psi)ds \; ,$$
and this is called the Duhamel formula. Now taking the derivative you get
$$e^{itD_x^2}xe^{-itD_x^2}\psi=x\psi -i\int_0^t e^{isD_x^2}[x,D_x^2]e^{-isD_x^2}ds=x\psi -i\int_0^t e^{isD_x^2}(D_x[x,D_x]+[x,D_x]D_x) e^{-isD_x^2}\psi ds\; .$$
Now the commutator $[x,D_x]=i$, and $D_X$ commutes with $e^{isD_x^2}$ hence
$$e^{itD_x^2}xe^{-itD_x^2}\psi=x\psi + 2D_x\int_0^te^{-isD_x^2}e^{isD_x^2}\psi ds=(x+2tD_x)\psi\; .$$
The result can then be extended to any $\psi\in D(x)\cap D(D_x)$ such that $e^{-itD_x^2}\psi\in D(x)$.